# How to access a class through its object literal's variable?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Say I have a simple class:

```
class Folder {
   constructor() {
      this.title = "a folder";
      this.dropdownInstance = {
         element: document.createElement("div")
      }
   }
}
```

and I store the `element` of `dropdownInstance` somewhere in my DOM.

Say another Object has an `EventListener` on that `element`, and that object wants to access `Folder`, is it possible to do so?

Basically going from `element` -> `dropdownInstance` -> `Folder` which holds its `dropdownInstance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will need some type of referencing system. This is what jQuery allows with the [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to attach arbitrary data to DOM elements.

I would probably use a simple array:

```js
const folders = [];

class Folder {
    constructor(){
        this.title = "a folder";

        this.dropdownInstance = {
            element: document.createElement("div")
        }

        folders.push([this.dropdownInstance.element, this]);
    }

    static getFromElement(el) {
        const folder = folders.find(f => f[0] === el);
        return folder ? folder[1] : null;
    }

}
```

You could then simply call Folder.getFromElement(el) to retrieve the Folder instance.